# Resizing image into a div

Tags: html, css, image

I have a div with percentages as values, and an image i need to fit in it.
The width should be resized to fit the div, whereas the height of the image that exceeds the div should be hidden.

(a clearer visual explanation)
[image: want]

[this is what I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/5UJRB/6/)(edit: pasted the wrong link, my bad)

the html:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img  class="imgofcrap" src="http://physictourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Grand-Canyon-National-Park-Arizona.jpg" />
</div>
```

the css:

```
div.wrap {
width: 20%;
height: 5%; 
overflow:hidden;
        border: 2px solid black; }

img.imgofcrap{
width: 100%;
    height: auto; }
```

Comment: Something like this? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/5UJRB/5/) Also you are using a percentage as the height but the div has nothing to get the height of. If you want to use it like that you need to set, `html, body { height: 100%; }`

Comment: I love that you have a hand-drawn picture of what you want.  Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Background image would be better than inline image.

Comment: Why don't you use JQuery for it. It will do it more precisely.

Comment: The problem is that you're using percentages for height, in most cases this won't work, make sure that the parent has a height. Your css should work if you try it out with a fixed height.

Comment: @Ruddy precisely, but i need the height to be a percentage as well..

Comment: Thumbs up on the hand drawn image! Easier to visualize what you're wanting things to do...

Comment: @GwenWong As I said in my comment just add the last bit I put. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/5UJRB/7/).

Comment: @VeerShrivastav im abit ashamed to say my jquery is embarrassing at best D: say I use jquery..how would one go about doing that?

Comment: @GwenWong jQuery is not needed for this at all. This is basic CSS. :) Also check out my answer.

Comment: @Ruddy That makes a lot of sense. Of course height cant be a percentage-- i dont know what I was thinking :) If you'd like to submit that as an answer i'll accept it!

Comment: @GwenWong My answer is up there, and heights can be percentages. They just been be a percentage of something. I will write up a little more a bit later if you would like.

Comment: @xDaevax Glad you liked it! :D seemed only right...i tried to explain it in words and even -I- didnt understand it C:

Comment: @ChristopherHarris Cheeers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple and you was close.

So we just want to use the `width` of the `img` so we set that as `100%`. As the parent has a `width` it will use that. Now the parent you have set as a percentage `height`. But the `div` has no parent with an `height`. So we set it using:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

So now we have:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

div.wrap {
    width: 20%;
    height: 6%;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
img.imgofcrap {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/5UJRB/7/)

Answer (score 2):

I thing so you are looking for a responsive image.
so please cheack below JSfiddle URL

```
img.imgofcrap{
    max-width:100%;
    height: auto;
    display:block;
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ErAshu/5UJRB/2/)

Comment: This scales the images. The OP wants the overflow hidden and the size retained.

Answer (score 1):

Change to this:

```
img.imgofcrap{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; 
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5UJRB/4/)

Also take a look here [The difference between width:auto and width:100%](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201112/the_difference_between_widthauto_and_width100/)

Comment: This scales the images. The OP wants the overflow hidden and the size retained.

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for a background cover solution: if you only have to use the image like you showed there and only in latest browsers i would go for

```
<div class="wrap"></div>



div.wrap {
    width: 20%;
    height: 5%; 
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 2px solid black; 
    background: transparent url("http://physictourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Grand-Canyon-National-Park-Arizona.jpg") center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/nomisweb/2T7gG/3/)**

if you need ie7+ support i made a small project which covers that - feel free to use it or extended it to your needs:

https://github.com/sp90/backgroundCover